# Best practice for processing percent change over a given timespan when some data points are 0?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a dataset where some data points are 0 and I'm trying to process it so that each data point is instead a percent change from the previous point. The problem is that some of these points have the value of 0, and so sometimes calculating percent change from the previous data point of 0 will lead the current data point to equal infinity.

Is there a better way to handle percent change or is it fine for a recurrent neural network to use infinity as some of its data points?

I am feeding this data into a recurrent neural network backed by Keras.

Comment: Why not work with absolute changes and simply calculate the percent changes outside of the model?

Comment: Unfortunately the data I'm working with is exponential in nature and thus it would seem to me that utilizing percent change in the data being fed into the RNN is the way to go. I may be wrong here though and am definitely open to suggestions and new ideas.

Comment: Is there a minimum value?

Comment: Yep, the possible values would be anything from zero up to positive infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical problem in machine learning. In dealing with such problems you need to apply a *so-called* smoothing which is usually adding a small constant `eps` to denumerator. So you need to apply following transformation:

```
ration = next_step / (eps + small_step)
```

I advise you to set `eps` to be greater than `1e5` as `1e6` is a decimal point precision of `float32` format used in `keras`.